# Issue setting parameters in MS Query

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, ms-query

I have an Access database that is connecting to an Excel dashboard. I have a query that performs a task, but needs a few dates set as criteria before it can complete the query. I'm using parameters to point to a few spots within the dashboard to retrieve the dates needed for the query to perform correctly.

The dates in the the Access field are set to `date/time` and the date in the dashboard are also set to `date/time`. For some reason, when I try and run the query, its says `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression]`. As I mentioned earlier, both the Excel location that it's pointing to, and the Access field it's connecting to, are set to the same type.

If I hard code the dates into the SQL, the query runs perfectly, it will also run correctly when typing them into the parameter popup window. The only time this doesn't work, is when I try and point it to a date within the dashboard, resulting in the error message above. Here is my code for the query:

```
SELECT tbl_Master_Phone.ID, 
  tbl_Master_Bill_Cycle_Date.Bill_Cycle_Date, 
  tbl_Master_ECPD.Client_ID, 
  tbl_Master_Client.Client_Name, 
  tbl_Master_ECPD.ECPD_ID, 
  tbl_Master_Account.Account_Number, 
  tbl_Master_Phone.Wireless_Number, 
  tbl_Master_Username.User_Name, 
  tbl_Master_Cost_Center.Cost_Center, 
  Max(tbl_Inventory.Bill_Cycle_Date) , 
  tbl_Master_Device.Device_Model, 
  tbl_Master_Device.Device_Type, 
  tbl_Inventory.Device_ID, 
  tbl_Inventory.SIM, 
  tbl_Inventory.Contract_Activate_Date, 
  tbl_Inventory.Contract_End_Date, 
  tbl_Inventory.Upgrade_Eligibility_Date
    FROM tbl_Master_Username 
      INNER JOIN ((tbl_Master_Client 
      INNER JOIN ((tbl_Master_Account 
      INNER JOIN tbl_Master_ECPD 
        ON tbl_Master_Account.ECPD_ID = tbl_Master_ECPD.ID) 
      INNER JOIN (tbl_Master_Device 
      INNER JOIN (tbl_Master_Phone 
      INNER JOIN tbl_Inventory 
        ON tbl_Master_Phone.ID = tbl_Inventory.Wireless_Number) 
        ON tbl_Master_Device.ID = tbl_Inventory.Device_Model) 
        ON tbl_Master_Account.ID = tbl_Inventory.Account_Number) 
        ON tbl_Master_Client.ID = tbl_Master_ECPD.Client_ID) 
      INNER JOIN (tbl_Master_Bill_Cycle_Date 
      INNER JOIN (tbl_Master_Cost_Center 
      INNER JOIN tbl_Phone_Details 
        ON tbl_Master_Cost_Center.ID = tbl_Phone_Details.Cost_Center)
        ON tbl_Master_Bill_Cycle_Date.Bill_Cycle_Date = tbl_Phone_Details.Bill_Cycle_Date) 
        ON tbl_Master_Phone.ID = tbl_Phone_Details.Wireless_Number) 
        ON tbl_Master_Username.ID =  tbl_Phone_Details.Username
Where ((tbl_Inventory.Bill_Cycle_Date<=?))
GROUP BY tbl_Master_Phone.ID, 
         tbl_Master_Bill_Cycle_Date.Bill_Cycle_Date, 
         tbl_Master_ECPD.Client_ID, 
         tbl_Master_Client.Client_Name, 
         tbl_Master_ECPD.ECPD_ID, 
         tbl_Master_Account.Account_Number, 
         tbl_Master_Phone.Wireless_Number, 
         tbl_Master_Username.User_Name, 
         tbl_Master_Cost_Center.Cost_Center, 
         tbl_Master_Device.Device_Model, 
         tbl_Master_Device.Device_Type, 
         tbl_Inventory.Device_ID, 
         tbl_Inventory.SIM, 
         tbl_Inventory.Contract_Activate_Date, 
         tbl_Inventory.Contract_End_Date, 
         tbl_Inventory.Upgrade_Eligibility_Date
HAVING ((tbl_Master_Bill_Cycle_Date.Bill_Cycle_Date>=?)
      AND (tbl_Master_ECPD.Client_ID=?) 
      AND (tbl_Master_Bill_Cycle_Date.Bill_Cycle_Date<=?));
```

As you can see, there are parameters set up right after the `WHERE` statement, and three more after the `HAVING`. The second parameter after the `HAVING` works fine, but the three parameters requiring dates are the ones throwing up the error. If the datatypes are the same, what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Excel can get quite odd with dates and MS Access requires unambiguous dates, perhaps you could post the Excel code that supplies the parameters?

Comment: PS have a look at aliases at some time, they make SQL much more readable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the SQL that MS Query build after setting things up in the design view. As for the Excel code, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Are you wanting the cell location, and where the parameter is pointing to?

Comment: Nope :) I have lost contact with what you are doing. I much prefer to write my own stuff so I know what is going on. Microsoft offers innumerable shortcuts, but I have rarely found them sufficiently useful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue can be fixed by changing the date in the excel file to a text field rather than a date. This solved the issue.

Comment: It is not a good idea to have dates as text. Check the field type in MS Access. A text date can lead to 12 January being 1 December.

Comment: I figured this would not be the best method, but it is the only thing that I have found that works. Field types in Access are all set correctly, and so where the ones in Excel (until I changed them). I'm open to a better solution, but in the meantime, I'll go this route until I can find a better way.